# Render array of arrays table in Angular using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of arrays (representing rows and columns) and I need to render an HTML table with the data.

Each row is an array of column values, for example: `$scope.table.row[0] = [123, 456, 789]`

This is my attempt (that doesn't work). Any ideas?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in table">
            <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post the entire data

Comment: $scope.table.row[0] = [123, 456, 789]; $scope.table.row[1] = [111, 222, 333]; $scope.table.row[2] = [444, 555, 777]

Comment: `$table` vs `table`

Comment: Then you need either `<tr ng-repeat="row in table.row">` or ` 
table[0] = [123, 456, 789]; table[1] = [111, 222, 333]; table[2] = [444, 555, 777]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need to iterate over `table.row` or make `table` an array of arrays itself. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8wfL0KC9r3AA7SLoY1n?p=preview).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in table.row">
            <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

OR

```
table = [ [123, 456, 789], [111, 222, 333], [111, 222, 333]]

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in table">
            <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `*ngFor` like this:

```
rows = [['a1','a2', 'a3'],['b1','b2', 'b3'],['c1','c2', 'c3']]'
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <td *ngFor="let item of row">
        {{ item }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

result:

```
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3
```